# Paper_trail and Kaminari problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, kaminari

I have a ActiveRecord model from paper_trail gem called 'Version'.
I want to create resource with displaying  version records.
But Kaminari doesn't add 'page' scope to Version.
Any model has 'page' methods but Version doesn't

Example:

```
Version.methods.grep /page/
 => [] 
MyAnyModel.methods.grep /page/
=> [:page, :default_per_page]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bug of kaminari gem -

details are here : https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/pull/119

try to use

```
gem 'kaminari', :git=>"https://github.com/Casecommons/kaminari.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

**Kaminari.paginate_array**(my_array_object).page(params[:page])

resource:
https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari